# Is it safe to use floats in YAML hashes with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml, floating-accuracy

If I have a YAML file like

```
--- 
2.1: my product version
```

without any quotation marks, Ruby will treat the `2.1` as a Float (at least under Syck - I'm not sure about Psych).

Are there any risks in using a Float as a hash's key, so long as all of the other occurences of the key are either from a YAML file or literals from Ruby?

Comment: A version "number" is not actually a floating point number or even a number of any kind, it is more like sequence of integers (`[2,1,11]`) that is written in a peculiar way (`2.1.11`). So the problem behind the question is moot :)

Comment: @muistooshort: My question is can I be lazy and not use quotation marks to escape it or not.

Comment: I haven't tried it with `Hash`, but it causes problems with `RBTree` (at least with Psych): 
`'@9.884112959068247e-09' is not allowed as an instance variable name`